# Windows Server 2019 - New Microsoft Teams & WindowsApps Permissions

Tags: microsoft-teams, windows-server-2019, microsoft, citrix, vdi

While preparing for the rollout of the new MS Teams version that will replace the old one in March, we created a new template image for our VDI infrastructure (Citrix) running Windows Server 2019.

Teams was installed using DISM according to the official documentation by Microsoft here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/new-teams-vdi-requirements-deploy

After installation, Team could not be started by any user, administrator or otherwise, giving an insufficient access rights error.
We managed to solve the issue by taking ownership away from TrustedInstaller for the WindowsApps folder and manually adding Read&Execute rights to Authenticated Users for the Teams folder.

We would still like to know why and how this happened, so if anyone has encountered this issue before and/or has any insight to how this could be solved differently/permanently, please share!

Comment: What is the exact error message, and when do you see it (when their profile is created/the app is provisioned/they try and start the app)? What led you to try changing permissions on the appx volume? `dism.log` will show certain kinds of provisioning issues, but it can be pretty verbose. The troubleshooting steps here say a november update fixed an installation issue, in case your template gets those later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/new-teams-troubleshooting-installation . You might also have better luck asking on serverfault.com (or citrix support)